# Is it possible to find a standard deviation for a sample with only its average or mean available?

Tags: statistics

I have four groups each with a sample size of 84 and I want to run a t-test on them but I have no clue what their standard deviations are. Is there any way to find the standard deviations or do I have to re-research all of my data?

Comment: To be clear. This is your own research, but you do not still have the original data?

Answer (score 0):

If your 4 groups are given as the 84 samples of values, then you can calculate the unbiased empirical standard deviation estimator (you can look it up online) for each of the groups from the samples. If all you have is the means of the 4 groups, and not the samples, then no, there is nothing you can do to run a standard $t$-test. However if you can come up with a prior distribution on the standard deviations (based on your beliefs about the samples), and come up with a prior on the means under the hypothesis they are different (and an improper flat prior should be fine), then you can compute the posterior odds ratio for the hypothesis that the means are different versus the hypothesis that the means are the same. That would be a Bayesian approach.